# Second order section digital Bandpass

Tags: matlab, bandpass, digital

**Does anyone have a ressouce on how I can calculate second order section bandpass coefficients?**

What I tried allready:

I used following formulas from the Book Electronic Circuits (U.Tietze, Ch. Schenk) for the Lowpass:[image]
My coefficients match exaclty (difference is max 2e-14) with the second order sequions of MATLAB for the same lowpass.

For a bandpass filter I used following formulas:
[image]

The results differ quite alot from MATLAB, expecially if the order is higher than 2.
Also I dont think I can apply the formulas direcly for second order sections because the coefficients only depend on constant values.

Comment: This page may be what you need:  http://www.iowahills.com/A4IIRBilinearTransform.html

Comment: Thanks for oyur reply. I will check it out and make an update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the formulas from the textbook for the bandpass are not accurate.

I used following approach to calculate second order sections given an analogue filter lowpass. As an example following code displays the coefficients for a 4th order bandpass, calculated from a second order lowpass protopye.

1. Paramters

   `fs = 1000;
   fs1 = 200;
   fs2 = 300;
   w1 = 2*pi*fs1/fs;
   w2 = 2*pi*fs2/fs;
   Omega1 = 2*tan(w1/2);
   Omega2 = 2*tan(w2/2);
   syms s z Om2 Om1 a1 b1 A0
   % apply LP to BP transformation
   G_s_BP = subs(H_s, s, (s^2 + Om1*Om2)/(s*(Om2 - Om1)));`
2. Start with analogue transfer function H_s

   `H_s = A0 / (1 + a1*s + b1*s^2);
   % apply LP to BP transformation
   G_s_BP = subs(H_s, s, (s^2 + Om1*Om2)/(s*(Om2 - Om1)));`
3. Digital conversion with bilinear transformation

   `G_z_BP = subs(G_s_BP, s, 2*(( z - 1)/(z + 1)));
   % order polynomial such that coefficients can be read out
   coeffs_z = collect(G_z_BP, z)`

   Those coeffs_z are very similar to the ones given by the iowahills software
4. The band-pass filter coefficients then can be calculated with any analogue low-pass prototype, just enter numerical values on read out coefficients from coeffs_z